# Thunderbird window gets stuck maximized with no window controls

Tags: 14.04, unity, thunderbird, window-manager

My Thunderbird opens up maximized and without any window controls available. When this happens Unity's left sidebar disappeares - here's the screenshot of my *entire desktop*.

[image]

I tried removing some of the files from Thunderbird profile directory `~/.thunderbird/########.default` to try restore the window, but no luck. In safe mode

```
$ thunderbird --safe-mode
```

the issue disappears, but I don't if it's possible to extract those correct window settings into my profile.

Any ideas on how to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This did not help: the only thing helped was

First exit Firefox, then rename localstore.rdf and xulstore.json in the profiles directory of thunderbird:

```
cd ~/.thunderbird/your_profile
mv localstore.rdf localstore.rdf.bak
mv xulstore.json xulstore.json.bak
```

The only thing you have to do now is to rearrange your frames within firefox.

Answer (score 0):

It was just enough to start in safe mode and tick a box "Reset Toolbars and Controls"

[image]